# How to make a dates table on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have this spreadsheet in the picture... I want to fill up to 30/ago but the only way I know is to fill by hand...

What would be the formula to drag this horizontally and it increment by 1 per column?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=COLUMN() & "/ago"
```

it returns `1/ago` in first column, `2/ago` is second and so on.

Also you can adjust formula, say:

```
=(COLUMN() -3) & "/ago"
```

returns `1/ago` in column 4, `2/ago` in column 5 and so on.

[image]

**Another way:** in starting cell, say `B4` wirte `1/ago`. Then in next cell, `C4` in our case, write

```
=COUNTA($B$4:B$4)+1 & "/ago"
```

and drag across

[image]